# Get data from ajax and pass the data to view in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm developing a admin site for a hotel.

I have a edit button(it's icon tag) on each row of staff table. When click the edit button it will send data to a form at another site by ajax. But browser returns ajax error if I load view of editBooking

`$this->load->view('Booking/viewBookingView').`

**My js:**

```
$(".editBooking").click((event)=>{
          var table_data = [];
          var $row_data = $(event.target).parent().parent();

          vdata = {
            'name': $($row_data[0]).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
            'arrivalDate': $($row_data[0]).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
            'departureDate': $($row_data[0]).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
            'roomType': $($row_data[0]).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
            'quantity': $($row_data[0]).find('td:eq(4)').text()
          };// get data of row

          table_data.push(vdata);
          var data = { 'data_table' : table_data};
          console.log(data)
          $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'GET',
            url: '<?php echo base_url('index.php/AdminBooking/viewBooking/edit')?>',
            crossOrigin: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            error: ()=>{
              alert('ajax failed');
            },
            success: (result)=>{
              alert('ajax success');
              console.log(result.check)
            }
          })
        })
```

**My php controller:**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST, OPTIONS");

class ViewBooking extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){

        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('Booking/viewBookingView');
    }

    public function edit(){
        $ajaxData = $this->input->post('data_table');

        $data = array(
            'name' => $ajaxData[0]['name']
        );

        $this->load->view('Booking/test.php',$data);
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        echo json_encode(array(
            'check' => $data['name']
            ));//Kiem tra json  hoat dong khong?
    }
}
```

I expect when I click the edit button the editpage will load with the data from table.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to store your clicked value in session or any other way then call that value in a function which will get the info from db table then return the function result in your next view.